# Put hyphen into equation

Tags: math-mode

Probably a pretty simple question, but how do I make a hyphen in a LaTeX equation?

Currently I have:

```
\begin{equation}
F-score = ....
\end{equation}
```

But it renders as *F - score* when I want *F-score*.

Suggestions?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436823/how-do-i-indicate-an-en-dash-while-in-math-mode-using-latex

Comment: Thank you! I think I saw that question, but didn't read it carefully enough. I was skimming for hyphens, not en-dashes....

Answer (score 7):

`F-score` will be interpreted as "F" "minus" "s" "c" "o" "r" "e". With the incorrect spacing that results from the five different consecutive letters, formatted as if it were the product of five variables.

Whenever you want text in math mode (you do here, since `F-score` is descriptive), you want a `\text...` command.

Since it looks like a variable, then `\textit{F-score}` is ok (formats in italic).

If you are going to reuse the variable, you can make a command:

```
\newcommand{\Fscore}{\ensuremath{\textit{F-score}}}%
```

Beware of `\DeclareMathOperator` which will use funky spacing. Its use is for mathematical functions like `sin` or `log` which take an argument: notice the funky spacing in `2\log 3`. This may be what you want: if you'll be writing, `F-score(\mu)` then you should use `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{amsopn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Fscore}{F-score}

\[
\Fscore = ...
\]
```